# how to build npgsql-3.0.3 binaries through sources on linux

Tags: npgsql

I want to know that how to build Npgsql binaries through Npsql-3.0.3 sources on linux. I don't want to use nuget mechanism to set up Npgsql on linux. Earlier i can see Npgsql.dll with Npgsql-2.2.4.3 sources for MS .net20/35/40/45 versions. So I can use mono to compile/execute my C# code to connect the database with support of Npgsql.dll as like below steps.

```
$opt/mono/bin/mcs npgsqltest.cs -r:/opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/System.Data.dll -r:/opt/PostgreSQL/Npgsql/ms.net45/Npgsql.dll

$ /opt/mono/bin/mono npgsqltest.exe
```

Now I don't see any Npgsql.dll with new 3.0.3 sources, so how can I build binaries through sources on linux.

Please guild me for this if any docs or references available.